# Array with loops Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I want to print put the elements in an array that only occur twice. So if, for example, number 2 occurs 3 or 4 times, it should not be printed. The code I've written so far is below.
The issue in my code is with the loop. For example, for the number 2, since `j=i+1` is the initialization condition, the inner loop won't read the elements before the `j`th location- since there is a 2 at index 6, it won't count the 2s before it, making the required condition true and displaying the 2. Is there a way to fix this?

```
public class Problem2 {

    public static void exactlytwice(int[] x) {
        int count, j;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            count = 0;
            for (j = i + 1; j < x.length; j++) {
                if (x[i] == x[j])
                    count++;
            }
            if (count == 1)   System.out.print(x[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] x = new int[15];
        x[0] = 2;
        x[1] = 2;
        x[2] = 2;
        x[3] = 13;
        x[4] = 44;
        x[5] = 44;
        x[6] = 2;
        x[7] = 63;
        x[8] = 63;
        x[9] = 90;
        x[10] = 1;
        x[11] = 2;
        x[12] = 150;
        x[13] = 150;
        x[14] = 180;

        exactlytwice(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could map the values in the array as keys to the number of occurrences then print the ones in the map with value=2.

Comment: Even though this has not much to do directly with your problem, instead of manually assigning an integer value to a specific index (location),  you could simply initialise the array in the following form: `int[] x = {2, 2, ...};`

Answer (score 3):

aside from the issue you wrote, the bigger problem I see with your code is that its inefficient. You are doing a loop inside a loop here, which is very slow (o(n^2)).

My suggestion is to keep a map of numbers->count, and then only take the ones that appear only twice in the map:

```
public static void exactlytwice(int[] x) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> counter = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (counter.contains(i)) {
           counter.put(i,1);
        } else {
           counter.put(i,counter.get(i)+1);
        }
    }

    for (Integer i : counter.keyset()) {
        if (counter.get(i) == 2) {
          System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use a `LinkedHashMap`, the result will be in the order the numbers are first seen. With `HashMap`, the order is undetermined, essentially appearing random. Or use a `TreeMap` and numbers will be in ascending order.

Comment: More importantly, from a performance perspective, use `Map<Integer, AtomicInteger>`, so you can increase the counter value without boxing a new `Integer`.

Comment: Btw, this solution will not preserve the order. And in that case we can use sorting solution as well :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Think about maintaining a seperate array/list which keeps track of all the elements that has been counted/printed by which you could just skip the same number that shows again down the array.
2. Or you could sort the array and then perform the whole logic to check for duplicates.

Comment: The separate array/list should actually be a `Map<Integer, AtomicInteger>`. I do like your 2nd option, assuming you're allowed to modify the array. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers provided, there are two more ways you could go about this:

1. If array modification is permitted, change elements already encountered to a dummy value, and skip the value if encountered. This reduces the time complexity to O(n) from O(n^2), but destroys the original array. Of course, this assumes that the acceptable integers are restricted to a certain set (thanks to @Dzmitry Paulenka for reminding me that I hadn't stated this explicitly). To keep the array, you could make a copy (although then the space complexity becomes O(n) ).
2. If any integer is acceptable, then create an `encountered` boolean array, all intialized to `false`. Change the locations of elements encountered in the original array to `true` in the `encountered` boolean array, and if the value is already `true`, it can be skipped. Again, time complexity O(n), but O(n) space complexity, and unlike in the second method of 1., does not require the permissible range of numbers (ints) to be restricted.
3. Alternately, simply make the initialization of j as `j=0`, and then ensure that only those numbers which don't have that number appearing before them are printed, i.e., that the number is printed only if it occurs at `j>=i` (thanks to @Nir Levy for pointing the `j>=i` requirement out). This is (slightly) more inefficient than the code already written, but the time complexity remains the same O(n^2).

Comment: your second solution is not good- numbers that appear twice will be printed twice (once for i>j and once for i<j)

Comment: And what is `dummy value` would be? :) If it's an `int`, than every value is valid.

Comment: @NirLevy : Thank you. Edited :)

Comment: @DzmitryPaulenka : Thank you. I had forgotten to state this explicitly. Fixed :)
(And another method without this requirement added in)

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, there is a solution without extra-map. It's still `O(n^2)`, but uses no extra memory. And It uses kind of fun idea.

First, we only need to output first occurence of a number, every other one is not relevant, because we either have more than 2 of them, or we've already output the first one.

Second, we can then indeed continue, from `i+1` element, because at this point, there are no elements equal to `ith`, that are earlier in array.

```
public static void exactlytwice(int[] x) {
    int count, j;

    TOP:
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        count = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (x[j] == x[i])
                // had this number earlier, so go to the next one.
                continue TOP;
        }
        for (j = i+1; j < x.length; j++) {
            if (i != j && x[i] == x[j])
                count++;
        }
        if (count == 1) System.out.print(x[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: concerning Dzmitry code the number 2 still prints on the screen

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8 you can achieve this using streams like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<Integer> list = Stream.of(12,1,3,4,2,3,7,6,7,3,1,8,4,12,33,45,78,36,8)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x->x, Collectors.summingInt(x->1)))
    .entrySet().stream().filter(x->x.getValue()==2)
    .collect(ArrayList<Integer>::new,(x,y)->x.add(y.getKey()),ArrayList<Integer>::addAll);
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

The result is :

```
[1, 4, 7, 8, 12]
```

Comment: Second ```.collect(...);``` can be ```.map(x -> x.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList());```.

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

public class Writer {  
    private int counter; 
    private Random generator = new Random();
    private List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

public Writer(int n){
    populate(n);
}

private final void populate(int n){
    for(int i = 0; i != n; i++){
        data.add(generator.nextInt(10));
    }
}

private final void reset(){
    this.counter = 0;
}

public final void occurence(){
    for(int dp : data){
        for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++){
            if(dp == data.get(i)){
                counter += 1;
            }
        }
        map.put(dp, counter);
        reset();
    }
}

public final void filter(int d){
    for(int key : map.keySet()){
        if(map.get(key) == d){
            System.out.println("Key: " + key + " Value: " + map.get(key));
        }
    }
}

public void rawData(){
    System.out.println(data.toString());
}

public void output(){
    System.out.println(map.toString());
}
```

**Initiate:**

```
// Create instance of Writer class and generate '100' random numbers
Writer writer = new Writer(100);

// Output raw data          
writer.rawData();

// Process data
writer.occurence();

// Filter numbers with occurence '10'
writer.filter(10);

// Output processed data
writer.output();
```

**Output (*from from calling filter(10)*):**

```
   Key: 3 Value: 10
   Key: 8 Value: 10
```